# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write', youtube-dl kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, youtube-dl

I am currently working on a small project which requies youtube-dl to work kivy environment. I have python 3.8.3, Kivy 1.11.1, youtube-dl 2020.5.8. Other than this issue kivy is working fine with python3.8.

I get this error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'` while try to fetch information about a youtube video using youtube-dl

It does works with a few link and does not work with many others.

This error has already is already present on youtube-dl's github page [[here]][1], but I could not find any solution.

These are the two following cases with a reproducible example.

**Case 1**

```
import youtube_dl
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MusicApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Example')


ydl_opts = {
    'outtmpl': '%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'audio-format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'])
```

***Output***

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/adarsh/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-06-23_1.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2(['text_pango'] ignored)
[youtube] BaW_jenozKc: Downloading webpage
[download] Resuming download at byte 215799
[download] Destination: youtube-dl test video ''_ä↭.f137.mp4
[download] 100% of 2.11MiB in 00:07.90KiB/s ETA 00:00
[download] Destination: youtube-dl test video ''_ä↭.f140.m4a
[download] 100% of 154.06KiB in 00:00.07KiB/s ETA 00:00
[ffmpeg] Merging formats into "youtube-dl test video ''_ä↭.mp4"
Deleting original file youtube-dl test video ''_ä↭.f137.mp4 (pass -k to keep)
Deleting original file youtube-dl test video ''_ä↭.f140.m4a (pass -k to keep)
[ffmpeg] Destination: youtube-dl test video ''_ä↭.mp3
Deleting original file youtube-dl test video ''_ä↭.mp4 (pass -k to keep)
```

**Case 2**

```
import youtube_dl
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MusicApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Example')


ydl_opts = {
    'outtmpl': '%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'audio-format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTj4wVJAbNg'])
```

***Output***

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/adarsh/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-06-23_2.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2(['text_pango'] ignored)
[youtube] nTj4wVJAbNg: Downloading webpage
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "temp/tmp.py", line 21, in <module>
     ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTj4wVJAbNg'])
   File "/home/adarsh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 2018, in download
     res = self.extract_info(
   File "/home/adarsh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 808, in extract_info
     return self.process_ie_result(ie_result, download, extra_info)
   File "/home/adarsh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 863, in process_ie_result
     return self.process_video_result(ie_result, download=download)
   File "/home/adarsh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 1644, in process_video_result
     self.process_info(new_info)
   File "/home/adarsh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 1902, in process_info
     self.report_warning(
   File "/home/adarsh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 613, in report_warning
     self.to_stderr(warning_message)
   File "/home/adarsh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 527, in to_stderr
     self._write_string(output, self._err_file)
   File "/home/adarsh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 506, in _write_string
     write_string(s, out=out, encoding=self.params.get('encoding'))
   File "/home/adarsh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/utils.py", line 3174, in write_string
     out.buffer.write(byt)
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Please suggest even if there are some workarounds.

**EDIT** :
I passed a logger to youtube-dl taken from their github page

```
class MyLogger(object):
    def debug(self, msg):
        print("DEBUG " + msg)
        pass

    def warning(self, msg):
        print("WARNING " + msg)
        pass

    def error(self, msg):
        print("ERROR " + msg)
```

I needed to write my own logger at later point to get the progress of download. So I am going with this solution.
[1]: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/22109

Answer (score 2):

I am working on a similar project and got the same error.

I catched Exceptions and print the traceback

```
import traceback

... 

  try:
     with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(self.ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([self.url])
  except Exception as inst:
     print(inst)
     tb = traceback.format_exc()
     print(tb)
     pass
```

and I got this :

```
'str' object has no attribute 'write'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odrevet/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 797, in extract_info
    ie_result = ie.extract(url)
  File "/home/odrevet/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 530, in extract
    ie_result = self._real_extract(url)
  File "/home/odrevet/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/generic.py", line 2277, in _real_extract
    % (url, url), expected=True)
youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError: 'qsd' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  youtube-dl "ytsearch:qsd" ) to search YouTube

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/main.py", line 81, in run
    download_retcode = ydl.download([self.url])
  File "/home/odrevet/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 2019, in download
    url, force_generic_extractor=self.params.get('force_generic_extractor', False))
  File "/home/odrevet/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 820, in extract_info
    self.report_error(compat_str(e), e.format_traceback())
  File "/home/odrevet/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 625, in report_error
    self.trouble(error_message, tb)
  File "/home/odrevet/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 578, in trouble
    self.to_stderr(message)
  File "/home/odrevet/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 527, in to_stderr
    self._write_string(output, self._err_file)
  File "/home/odrevet/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 506, in _write_string
    write_string(s, out=out, encoding=self.params.get('encoding'))
  File "/home/odrevet/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/utils.py", line 3180, in write_string
    out.buffer.write(byt)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

By looking to the function's name in the stack, we can see that our error occure when ytdl try to report another error (in this case : "youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError: 'qsd' is not a valid URL", because I entered 'qsd' in my program instead of a valid url).

By looking in YoutubeDl.py in the function to_stderr we can see that out is supposed to be sys.stderr, and in utils.py in the function where the error occure :

```
def write_string(s, out=None, encoding=None):
    print(type(out))    # I added this line
    if out is None:
        out = sys.stderr
    assert type(s) == compat_str

    if sys.platform == 'win32' and encoding is None and hasattr(out, 'fileno'):
        if _windows_write_string(s, out):
            return

    if ('b' in getattr(out, 'mode', '')
            or sys.version_info[0] < 3):  # Python 2 lies about mode of sys.stderr
        byt = s.encode(encoding or preferredencoding(), 'ignore')
        out.write(byt)
    elif hasattr(out, 'buffer'):
        enc = encoding or getattr(out, 'encoding', None) or preferredencoding()
        byt = s.encode(enc, 'ignore')
        out.buffer.write(byt)    # Error on line 3180
    else:
        out.write(s)
  out.flush()
```

stderr has a buffer attribute according to the hasattr elif check, the problem is how Kivy is handling the error stream. According to the print I added in write_string, stderr is redefined as a <class 'kivy.logger.LogFile'> which do have a buffer attribute like the Stream it's supposed to be, but this attribute is a simple String.

See https://kivy.org/doc/stable/_modules/kivy/logger.html

```
class LogFile(object):

    def __init__(self, channel, func):
        self.buffer = ''     # <-- a str
        self.func = func
        self.channel = channel
        self.errors = ''
```

I don't known if it's possible to parameter kivy to use standard streams for stderr but I will check. Meanwhile catch the exception and print backtrace to at least have the original error before the "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred"

edit: you can redirect stderr to a file

```
sys.stderr = open('./stderr', 'w')
```

Comment: If you are working on a similar project. Can you please try to answer this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62576040/how-to-use-ffmpeg-on-android-kivy-python3-youtube-dl). I am stuck on this since last 2 days. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when running my kivy app using youtube_dl on Android to download the audio track of a single video. The download of the same video audio worked ok on Windows 10.

I fixed the problem by changing the audio format in the youtube_dl options. Here's the code excerpt:

```
if os.name == 'posix':
    # on AndroidAndroid, FFmpegExtractAudio not available !
    self.ydlOutTmplFormat = '/%(title)s.mp3'

    self.ydl_opts = {
        #'format': 'bestaudio/best', # for unknown reason, not working on
                                     # Android when used by AudioDownloaderGUI !
        'format': 'worstaudio/worst',# This fixes the error "AttributeError:
                                     # 'str' object has no attribute 'write'"
        'quiet': YOUTUBE_DL_QUIET
    }
else:
    self.ydlOutTmplFormat = '\\%(title)s.%(ext)s'
    
    self.ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '128',
        }],
        'quiet': YOUTUBE_DL_QUIET
    }
```

I do not have any explanation why this modification solves the problem. When using youtube_dl on Android in a demo program not using kivy, the problem does not happen. Here's my demo code:

```
import os, re
import youtube_dl

if os.name == 'posix':
    targetAudioDir = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/Audiobooks/test_youtube_dl'
    ydl_opts = {
        'outtmpl': targetAudioDir + '/%(title)s.mp3',
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        #'format': 'worstaudio/worst',
        'quiet': False
    }
else:
    targetAudioDir = 'D:\\Users\\Jean-Pierre\\Downloads\\Audiobooks\\test_youtube_dl'
    ydl_opts = {
        'outtmpl': targetAudioDir + '\\%(title)s.%(ext)s',
        #'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'format': 'worstaudio/worst',
        'postprocessors': [{
                            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                            'preferredquality': '96',
                        }],
    'quiet': False
    }

singlevideoUrl = 'https://youtu.be/Eqy6M6qLWGw'

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    # downloading single video
    meta = ydl.extract_info(singlevideoUrl, download=False)
    videoTitle = meta['title']
    ydl.download([singlevideoUrl]) # not playable by kivy SoundLoader
    print('{} audio track downloaded'.format(videoTitle))
```

Comment: For my Kivy app, even with the 'worstaudio/worst' format, on Android, it does not work perfectly: the video is downloaded and the audio extracted, but setting audio bookmarks does not work. The bookmarks have no effect. The unique solution is to download/extract the video on Windows 10 and then transferthe audio file on Android. Then, the bookmarks are efficient. For your information, I use the Smart Audiobook app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ak.alizandro.smartaudiobookplayer&hl=fr_CH&gl=US) to listen and bookmark my audio files

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved it using the `os` library.

- First I create a `convert.py` script for example with the YouTube.dl function.
- Second, in kivy instead of calling YouTube.dl, I save the link in a `.txt` file, then I call `os.system` (`python3 convert.py`) using the txt with the link to convert and ready.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).